# Whenever I update edmx file it changes model1.context.cs's class name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

Whenever I update edmx file, it automatically changes the class name and constructor name. How can I prevent it?

> Model1.context.cs

My code before update of edmx

```
 public partial class RKDYMEntities : DbContext
{
    public RKDYMEntities()
        : base("name=RKDYMEntities")
    {
    }
```

Code After Updates

```
public partial class Entities : DbContext
{
    public Entities()
        : base("name=Entities")
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to rename your Container class name then do follow below steps:

1. Open edmx file and click on Design surface
2. Press <kbd>F4</kbd> or right click and select properties.
3. Change property `Entity Container Name` to `RKDYMEntities`

Comment: This is helpful, and faster than editing the x.Context.cs file like I have been doing, but  is there a way to prevent "Update Model from Database" from renaming it to Entities every time there is a schema change?

Comment: if you follow these instructions and try to rename the context with something like "TEST_Entities" it will not work! Underscores are obviously not accepted in that way of renaming, but are accepted by manually renaming like OP used.

Comment: The solution provided by Jenish Rabadiya doesn't fix the issue, it only guides on how to rename it back to the name that was before. Has anyone found a solution that doesn't require renaming back to the old name, but rather keeping the context name after the update to .edmx is made?